# public void set in Java; What is it exactly?

Tags: java

What does `public void set` in Java, do? I've read that it 'Sets the value of a named option' so is it simply like a variable assignment in the form of a function or something? (Sorry, not really a Java programmer.)

Here is the code I'm analyzing:

```
public void set(String s, int value) {
  set(s, new Integer(value));
}
```

What's inside it anyway? (the `set(s,new Integer(value)`) I'm thinking the two 'sets' are entirely different things.

Please Help. Sorry if this is a simple question, but I'm just trying to confirm my thoughts about the subject.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`public void set(String s, int value)` is a method declaration, which is followed by a method body inside `{` ... `}`.

```
public void set(String s, int value)
\____/ \__/ \_/
   |     |   |
   |     |   '---- Method name
   |     |
   |     '-------- Method return type
   |
   '-------------- Access modifier
```

The line after the `{`:

```
set(s,new Integer(value))
```

is a method call, which calls the `set`-method with `s` and `new Integer(value)` as arguments.

Comment: I've actually thought about that, but I couldn't tell for sure because if it was as such, wouldn't it be just calling itself?

Comment: @Secret It could just be calling itself, but I assume you also have `set(String s, Integer value)` in which case having `set(String s, int value)` is only useful for backward compatibility (pre Java 5.0) as it wouldn't make sense from Java 5.0+

Comment: It doesn't look like very good practice anyway, since an `int` will automatically be cast to an `Integer` (unless the method is overloaded).  It may be Java < 1.5 though.

Comment: This code actually makes sense if the internal `set` is private and of type (Object, Object), e.g. if the internal method is putting values in a HashMap<Object, Object> - the different publicly visible set is useful because it gives a more specific type declaration for users.

Answer (score 4):

It's a method just like any other. There are no special semantics for methods namet `set`. The method will probably work akin to `Map.put` and will register the value under the string key supplied, but it could also start 10 threads and compute the meaning of life for all we know.

That "other" set method that is called inside the declaration could be a method with signature

```
set(String key, Object value)
```

or, also

```
set(String key, Integer value)
```

Both would work in the context, but I vote for the former since the latter would be redundant due to autoboxing.

Comment: If you want to compute the meaning of life with 10 threads, you will have to wait for a long time. A group of hyper-intelligent pan-dimensional beings actually did it with a super computer named Deep Thought (which surely used more than 10 threads) and it took him 7½ million years... So good luck on that. :P

Comment: Actually, you might save some time by skipping the checking of the answer. ^^

Comment: @brimborium If our algorithm is allowed to rely on prior work on the subject by those pan-dimensional beings, we already know that the answer to the question of the meaning of life (and some other things to boot) can be computed by a single thread, evaluating `6 * 7` :)

Comment: It's actually `What do you get if you multiply six by nine?`, but that method got mixed up by those highway builders. I am still mad at them! (Fun fact btw: If you calculate that in base 13 you get the correct result...)

Answer (score 0):

it's a function. `public` is the scope where the function is reachable (in this case you can call it from outside of the class), `void` is the return type, while void means there is no return value. set is the name of the function.

The Method seems to be a kind of interface to set any variable to the given value from outside of the class (while it only calls another Method 'set' with the String and a new Integer-Object containing the value, propably to reach another overloaded function which could look like

```
private void set(String s, Integer value)
```

you should look for something like that, perhaps your code will become clear then.

Comment: It's not a function, it's a method.

Answer (score 0):

In here public means Access modifier if you use public you can access to that method outside of the class. instead of public you can use private,defaultand protected key word also. this is good link for learn about that [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/access-modifiers.html)

void means the return type in here you not return anything that's why use **void** if you need to return integer value you  have to use **int** instead of the void key word.
eg - public int getData(){} but if you specify the return type you have to return value.

in here set means method name it is not a key word. but in the java to set some values we use set word as an example **public void setName(){}** like wise.

(String s, Integer value) these are the parameters if you need to call that method you have to pass to objects of the specified classes. in here you have to pass string value and integer value. eg - set("Secret",1);